# Pow(x,n) in LeetCode using C++. AddressSanitizer 33

Tags: c++, algorithm, out-of-memory

I'm having an error that I don't know how to solve when trying to submit my solution on the Pow(x,n) problem on Leetcode.

```
double myPow(double x, int n) 
{
    if(n == 0) return 1;      //Power of 0 return 1
    int flag = 1;
    double result;
    if(n<0) flag = -1;      //check if negative power
    vector<double> myvec(n*flag,x);   //create a vector length of the power, filled with our number x
    result = accumulate(begin(myvec), end(myvec), 1.0, multiplies<>());   //multiply the elements of the vector
    return flag > 0? result : 1/result;     
}
```

The error I get is this:

```
==33==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: allocator is out of memory trying to allocate 0x3fffffff8 bytes
#7 0x7f44d265d82f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
==33==HINT: if you don't care about these errors you may set allocator_may_return_null=1
```

If I leave the "accumulate" line with a 1 instead of a 1.0, I'm getting the result as if the double x was an int (ex. 2.1^3=8). But when I'm changing it to 1.0 in order to take the decimal points from the double I get the above error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd get this working with simple multiplication first and then, if there's a compelling need, start looking into `std::vector`s  and `std::accumulate`. Personally I don't see any need.

Comment: If `n` is less than `0` you set `flag` to `-1` and then you do `myvec(n*flag,x)` - what do you expect from that calculation?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Positive n?

Comment: @JesperJuhl n and flag are both negative.

Comment: If the input n is a negative (ex. 2.1^ -3) I'm making my flag to be -1. That way when I'm initialising my vector (vector<double> myvec(n*flag,x)), I'm getting a positive size.

Comment: myPow(1.0, 1000000000) will try to allocate a _huge_ vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating too much memory. You can achieve the same result by using a simple `for` loop.

```
double res = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    res *= x;
```

Although it might give you TLE. So you'll need a better algorithm.

Comment: You are right. I tried the input 0.00001 , 2147483647 and it broke down. It was not the optimal solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this problem should be solved with `std::accumulate`, I might be wrong though.

This is an iterative solution, which will pass:

```
struct Solution {
    static const inline double myPow(double x, int64_t n) {
        double res = 1;
        int64_t m;

        if (n < 0) {
            m = -n;
            x = 1 / x;

        } else {
            m = n;
        }

        while (m) {
            if (m & 1) {
                res *= x;
            }

            x *= x;
            m >>= 1;
        }

        return res;
    }
};
```

Here is one of LeetCode's solutions:

```
class Solution {
public:
    double myPow(double x, int n) {
        long long N = n;
        if (N < 0) {
            x = 1 / x;
            N = -N;
        }
        double ans = 1;
        double current_product = x;
        for (long long i = N; i ; i /= 2) {
            if ((i % 2) == 1) {
                ans = ans * current_product;
            }
            current_product = current_product * current_product;
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/powx-n/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

#### For [interviews](https://leetcode.com/problemset/top-interview-questions/?listId=wpwgkgt):

- We'd like to write [bug-free](https://www.codegrip.tech/productivity/tips-to-write-bug-free-code-during-interview/) and [clean](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-cleaner-code-during-onsite-interviews) codes based on standards and conventions (e.g., [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>[1](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html), [2](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eeno/coding/CCodingStandard.html)</sup>, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), [2](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)</sup>, [java](/questions/tagged/java)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), [2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)</sup>, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)</sup>, [python](/questions/tagged/python)<sup>[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)</sup>, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)</sup>, [go](/questions/tagged/go)<sup>[1](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments)</sup>, [rust](/questions/tagged/rust)<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/)</sup>).

Comment: There might be a problem with precision for the final answer. Better to divide in the end.